# python data dictionary output

Tags: python, export-to-csv, data-dictionary

I have a list of key and values in a data dictionary format already

e.g.

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

How can this be put into a csv output where

```
key1,key2,key3
value1,value2,value3
```

Comment: For every row or are the keys just the first header? Have you seen the `csv` module and the `csv.DictWriter()` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> d = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
>>> ','.join(d.keys())
'key3,key2,key1'
>>> ','.join(d.values())
'value3,value2,value1'
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be a quick and easy way to get it out

Comment: np, feel free to mark this answer as correct by clicking the V mark :)

Comment: I apologized as I am very new to python. I am now iterate through out several name and they all getting the same dictionary key and value. How can i just print the key once and keep appending the value as per iteration.